# What did the High Priest do to Solembum or Angela?

Tags: inheritance-cycle

In *Inheritance*, the High Priest of Helgrind casts some sort of spell that Eragon doesn’t recognize. Oddly, it has little effect on its most obvious target, but does perturb Angela:

> As the werecat sailed through the air, the High Priest shouted
> something in the ancient language—Eragon did not recognize the word,
> but the sound of it was unmistakably that of the elves’ native
> language. Whatever the spell was, it seemed to have no effect on
> Solembum, although Eragon saw Angela stumble as if she had been
> struck.
>
> <sub>*Inheritance*</sub>

Is there any evidence to suggest what the Priest did or attempted?

Comment: Good question. I was wondering the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### To kill Solembum by compressing the air around him

> **What did the High Priest try to do to Solembum that caused Angela to stumble?**
>
> *The priest tried to kill Solembum using some obscure words in the ancient language (something to do with compressing the air around him, as I recall). However, the spell was stopped by the wards Angela had placed around Solembum.*
>
> <sub>[Reddit AMA 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/Eragon/comments/8fpwfo/i_am_christopher_paolini_ama_starting_2pm_mt/dy75wq8/?context=3)</sub>

Comment: Mmmm. Some details would be nice. Is the AMA ongoing?

Comment: @Adamant - I think so, but probably not for much longer.

Comment: @Adamant - I have added "some details". I hope you'll like them.